# Construct dynamic SQL queries in Go

Tags: mysql, sql, go, orm

I am not very experienced developer in backend, and I am trying to build the simple CMS. I use go and gin framework, and database/sql package to interact with DB. So, the question is that sometimes I have to perform very similar queries, but they are slightly different.
For example, sometimes I want to add `where` clause dynamically, or simply omit it. Or I have to create new row or updating existing – despite different query, they basically perform similar operations. Or I want to add `or` clause.

So, I write a lot of duplicated code. What is the best way to avoid it?

Comment: Have you checked projects like https://github.com/Masterminds/squirrel or https://github.com/gocraft/dbr ?

Comment: I've seen them, but due to educational purposes I've decided to go with plain SQL. So, any of these libraries is good enough to use as SQL builder?

Comment: I have preference for dbr, I m no one to say if there are good to use, i trust others for that, i can only tell they are helpful to manage the pain of sql. BTW, for education purpose I found this very interesting http://go-database-sql.org/